# How can I color a row in table I generated using stwe / DatatablesBundle?

Tags: symfony, datatables, bundle

How can I color a row in table I generated using stwe / DatatablesBundle? I want to achieve something like, the whole line marked in green (add appropriate class?) when status.id === 1 and marked to green when status.id === 2. I want to use LineFormatter (https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle/blob/v0.13/Resources/doc/lineFormatter.md) - not callbacks. Please note that the status.status_id column is not visible (it is just related to status.name from the database).

This is my Datatable.php file:

```
public function buildDatatable(array $options = array())
{

    $this->features->set(array(
        'auto_width' => true,
        'defer_render' => false,
        'info' => true,
        'jquery_ui' => false,
        'length_change' => true,
        'ordering' => true,
        'paging' => true,
        'processing' => true,
        'scroll_x' => false,
        'scroll_y' => '',
        'searching' => true,
        'state_save' => false,
        'delay' => 0,
        'extensions' => array(),
        'highlight' => false,
        'highlight_color' => 'red'
    ));

    $this->ajax->set(array(
        'url' => $this->router->generate('proposal_results'),
        'type' => 'GET',
        'pipeline' => 0
    ));

    $this->options->set(array(
        'display_start' => 0,
        'defer_loading' => -1,
        'dom' => 'lfrtip',
        'length_menu' => array(10, 25, 50, 100),
        'order_classes' => true,
        'order' => array(array(0, 'asc')),
        'order_multi' => true,
        'page_length' => 10,
        'paging_type' => Style::FULL_NUMBERS_PAGINATION,
        'renderer' => '',
        'scroll_collapse' => false,
        'search_delay' => 0,
        'state_duration' => 7200,
        'stripe_classes' => array(),
        'class' => Style::BOOTSTRAP_3_STYLE,
        'individual_filtering' => false,
        'individual_filtering_position' => 'head',
        'use_integration_options' => true,
        'force_dom' => false,
        'row_id' => 'id'
    ));

    $this->columnBuilder
        ->add('id', 'column', array(
            'title' => 'ID',
        ))
        ->add('client.name', 'column', array(
            'title' => 'Client name',
        ))
        ->add('client.surname', 'column', array(
            'title' => 'Client surname',
        ))
        ->add('client.code', 'column', array(
            'title' => 'Client Code',
        ))
        ->add('date_add', 'datetime', array(
            'title' => 'Date added',
            'date_format' => 'LLL'
        ))
        ->add('status.name', 'column', array(
            'title' => 'Status',
        ));
//            ->add('status.status_id', 'column', array(
//                'title' => 'Status Status_id',
//            ))
}
```

Comment: would like to know aswell

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by adding getLineFormatter to the Datatable.php file:

```
public function getLineFormatter()
{
    $formatter = function ($line) {
        if($line['status_id'] == 1) {
           $line['DT_RowClass'] = 'class_name';
        }
        return $line;
    };
    return $formatter;
}
```

In order for this to work you need to add the status_id as a column or a hidden column.